# DataTable and Kendo Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, datatable, kendo-grid

I'm using dynamic model in Kendo Grid. I send to the view DataTable object which has datetime column names (eg. 2019/9/1 12:00 AM, 2019/9/2 12:00 AM). Data type is String for all these columns. Unfortunately the browser shows column names without data and in console there is an error: Uncaught error - Invalid template.

The code is:

```
    @model DataTable

    @using System.Data

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<dynamic>()
.Name("raspored")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        if (Model.Columns.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
            {
                if (col.ColumnName == "Sifra")
                {
                    columns.Bound(col.ColumnName).Title("Šifra");
                }
                else if (col.ColumnName == "RadnoMesto")
                {
                    columns.Bound(col.ColumnName).Title("ORM");
                }
                else
                {
                    columns.Bound(col.DataType, col.ColumnName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
   .DataSource(ds => ds
 .Ajax()
 .Read(read => read.Action("Raspored_Read", "Home"))

)
 )
 )
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.  I couldn't get it working with dates/digits as a column name.  I resorted to prefixing the column name with a letter and removed separator symbols to make it work (eg Y20190101 or Y2019M01D01 ). I'm interested to see what the answer to this is too!

Comment: I have partially solved this. I return something like "date_yyyy-MM-dd" from controller to the view and then bound with column names. But I have another issue. :(  Every date column have NaN values in the cells. When debugging I can see that all data exist.

Comment: Why do I get NaN values in the cells? The data are strings. That's how those columns are defined.

Comment: Solved. Kendo Grid and JavaScript do not allow "-" in column names or variables. I've changed to date_yyyyMMdd when return data from controller and it works. :)

Comment: I managed to get it working too.  You could add an answer if you think it'll be useful for others :)